# Set jQuery drag event for every draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

In a jQuery heavy webapp that has about a dozen or so draggable divs, instead of manually adding the same drag event to each individually, is it possible to tell jQuery that every draggable should have the same drag event?

Comment: Give them a class? `$(".iAmDraggable").draggable({drag: ...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need more info, but can you do something like this:

```
<div class="draggable-div"></div>
$("div.draggable-div").each(someDragunction);
```

Comment: I have to get over the hurdle that classes aren't just for CSS. Thanks.